# The plot doesn't show up when I use Plot3D

Tags: plotting

In Mathematica help all the examples are given in a way that the function is written like:
Plot3D[{x^2 + y^2, -x^2 - y^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
I have a code that is huge and the function that I want to plot is calculated inside the code and assigned in a variabe named MyCriterion. I want to plot MyCriterion but no plot shows up. But if I copy and paste value shown in Out[4253] I can see the plot. but I want the plot in a way that if the MyCriterion changes I can see the corresponding plot. [image]

Comment: Use `Evaluate`, i.e., `Plot3D[Evaluate@MyCriterion, …]`

Comment: Thanks, Bob, I tried it but still it's not working.

Comment: Without your actual code that we can copy and execute, we can only guess. Post a minimal example (InputForm) that demonstrates the problem.